# Quick Questions about MSBuild copy task

Tags: .net, visual-studio, scripting, msbuild, publish

HI Guys,
Im newbie to MSBuild so may be some questions could sound stupid.

1. What are these extra files which gets generated while using aspnetcompiler like App_globa.asax.compiled,default.master.compiled etc....
2. I was trying to using copy task to copy the consanother iis hosted end points which is not web site(.ashx) files but it was copying all the .cs,.csproj etc.Is there anyway to exclude them. And also can msbuild maintain the foldername as it is while copying. because when Im using copy task. it is combining everything into one.

Comment: Question #1 is incomplete, and there seems to be a confusing typo in question #2.  If you could supply the actual MSBuild for your use of the Copy task that is not behaving as you expect, then I could help...

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <SourceDir Include="$(xfolder)\**\*" Exclude="**/*.cs"/>
  </ItemGroup>                                                        <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceDir)" DestinationFolder="$(Folder)\$(Folder)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true"   />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case described in your comment, you are Including files under $(xfolder) and only excluding files under the current directory, since your Exclude doesn't also specify $(xfolder), so basically unless $(xfolder) happens to be the current folder, you aren't excluding anything.  Also you are missing a wildcard, so you are only trying to exclude files named ".cs" and not "*.cs".  Fix your Exclude to be

```
Include="$(xfolder)**\*.*" Exclude="$(xfolder)**\*.cs"
```

Comment: I figured it out and that's exactly I did. BUt IM getting this error:Web.config" is an invalid value for the "DestinationFolder" parameter of the "Copy" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

Comment: Whatever you are passing to DestinationFolder has to resolve to a single path.  You can't pass an item (anything with @(..) ) to that argument.  You also will be losing all the recursive folder information (the ** resolved parts).  You may need to use DestinationFiles and an item transform.  Is the MSBuild in your comment above exactly what is in your build?  What is the value of $(Folder)?